# Issue plotting generated polygon grid to leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet, raster, r-sf, r-sp

I am trying to create a polygon grid to plot in leaflet, but am running into an error that I cannot seem to figure out:

```
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)

r <- raster(ext = extent(-10,0, -5, 5), res=c(1,1))
p <- rasterToPolygons(r) 
p <- st_as_sf(p)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(p)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in derivePolygons(data, lng, lat, missing(lng), missing(lat), "addPolygons") : 
  addPolygons must be called with both lng and lat, or with neither.
```

I know that this is being thrown by the `addPolygons()` call, but I cannot seem to figure out what is doing it or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing the polygon object in your `leaflet::addPolygons()` call by position; it will be passed to the second argument (since we are in a pipe).

The second position argument is `lng` for longitude. As a result your leaflet object will have longitude specified, and latitude missing.

What you need to do is pass the object by name = as `data` argument. This can happen both in your `addPolygons()` call or in the base `leafet()` call.

```
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(rgdal)

r <- raster(ext = extent(-10, 0, -5, 5), res=c(1,1))
p <- rasterToPolygons(r) 
p <- st_as_sf(p)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(data = p) # see what I have done? :)
```

[image: leaflet map showing as expected]